# how to do point to point communication in windows phone 7 over gprs

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, gprs

can somebody help in finding out any way about how we can do point to point communication with windows phone 7 and a desktop computer over gprs.

Please it has becoma a showstopper for our project..

Thanks

Edit 1:

Yahya, The computer is having internet and also gsm modem with a network provider sim and the mobile is also having a sim. Where ever they are they have internet and we want to see each other or can send msg to each other over gsm, because when a gsm modem having proper data enabled sim from a mobile network operator is attached to a computer then the computer should able to talk to the mobile over gprs, because the mobile is also holding a valid gprs enabled sim.

Comment: what do you mean ? is the desktop computer accessible via internet ? or is able able to receive gprs (highly doubtful) ? are both the Pc and the phone near enough to each other that bluetooth might work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that both your endpoints Windows Phone 7 and Desktop have a SIM (or modem with a SIM) inside, you surely know the phone numbers of those SIMs.

if you want to communicate via GSM or via SMS you can send a SMS (Short Message) from one to the other and parse received messages on both and check if the message comes from the other side by checking the sender number than parse the data in the message as needed.

Differently if you go over GPRS or Data Transfer and you are on the Internet then the desktop could host a web service in IIS for example so the Phone can directly connect to such web service and call a method passing the data required to be transferred.

in fact you only need the phone to know the IP address of your server or desktop and to connect and consume the web service via the Internet when data connection is available and if not you can send a SMS to the desktop' SIM card.